# Can't change shell in EC2 server

Tags: command-line

I am trying to change the default shell on Ubuntu server 13.10 on Amazon's AWS (AMI ami-ad184ac4).

I've tried:

```
~$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

But got:

```
Password: 
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

I've tried obvious passwords (e.g. `ubuntu`) but always got the same error message - `chsh: PAM: Authentication failure`.

Any idea why can't I change the default shell?

Answer (score 19):

Oddly enough, using `sudo` with the username was the answer:

```
$ sudo chsh ubuntu -s /bin/zsh
```